# Email column should allow null in AspNetUsers table

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I need to set email field as null in 'AspNetUsers' table. Sometime it use phone as username. So that I need set null email field

Comment: Add some more info, which version of .net (core 3 or 5), maybe a codesnippet for your specific problem …

Comment: Is your goal to modify the database table to reject inserts with a mull value? Which database vendor and version? Is your goal to modify the .NET code to report an error to the user? Your question lack details and context.